# Fastest way to call native methods from C#?

Tags: c#, performance, pinvoke

I have a giant C# wrapper library for a C++ DLL. The method used to call the methods is by caching delegates.

Basically, for every method in the C++ DLL, the C# wrapper contains a method signature with the SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity attribute for speed, and a corresponding delegate variable of type -*insert method name here*- so they are not generic delegates, but specific to the method header.

Example:

```
[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
internal delegate void RandomNativeMethod(int param1, float param2);

internal static readonly RandomNativeMethod randomNativeMethodDelegate;
```

The Delegates are populated in batch in a static constructor at the start of the application. Loading time is not an issue, and delegate calls are quite fast using this method.

Example:

```
//shortened code
static SampleStaticConstructor() {
       foreach (FieldInfo f in typeof(Delegates).GetFields(flags | BindingFlags.Public)) {
            address = GetAddress(f.Name);
            if (address == IntPtr.Zero) {
                method = coreClass.GetMethod(f.Name.Substring(2), flags);
                if (method != null)
                    f.SetValue(null, Delegate.CreateDelegate(f.FieldType, method));
            } else
                f.SetValue(null, Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(address, f.FieldType));
        }
}
```

Before manually adding caching, the library used direct P/Invoke calls without reflection through delegates. Calls were actually about 1.5 times slower when calling directly, hence reflection was implemented.

My question is, is there a possible setup that allows faster calling to native methods from C#? (initial loading times are irrelevant)

Comment: Please add some sample code to your question.

Comment: CLI may be a option see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI

Comment: I am not sure as to whether C++ CLI is actually faster, as it is still fundementally based on P/Invoke.

Comment: It can be faster, but you will have to write a branch mark to see if it is for YOUR code.

Comment: You have re-invented the pinvoke marshaller, the one that does the exact same thing from a simple [DllImport] attribute.  Without all the delegate pain.  And excessively micro-optimized to be as fast as possible.  You can't find out and compare until you try it.

Comment: Yes, before I added the delegate caching, method calling was actually slower surprisingly.